# Convert to date and use Peruvian Timezone

Tags: r, postgresql, dplyr

I have this data frame (data_loid), retrieved from a SQL query:

```
loid_last   last_modified_date
LIB3149     2020-05-29 19:10:13
```

And I want to extract only the date. So I tried this conversion:

```
data_loid <- data_loid %>% 
  mutate(loid_creation_date = as.Date(last_modified_date))
```

But it returns me:

```
loid_last   last_modified_date    loid_creation_date
LIB3149     2020-05-29 19:10:13   2020-05-30
```

I suspect that it's because of the timezone (I have to use Peruvian timezone), I tried to retrieve directly from the query using `SELECT loid_last, last_modified_date, date(last_modified_date) loid_creation_date FROM table where loid_last = 'LIB3149'` but it returns me `2020-05-30` instead of `2020-05-29`.

I tried this conversion:

```
data_loid <- data_loid %>% 
  mutate(loan_creation_date = as.Date(last_modified_date, tz = "PET"))
```

But it doesn't work. Please, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what type of column is `last_modified_date` after your have your SQL query in R? The documentation for `?timezones` might be helpful

Comment: `"PET"` isn't recognized, but `as.POSIXct("2020-05-29 19:10:13", tz = "America/Lima")` works (and therefore `as.Date` as well).

Comment: Hello @EJJ, column `last_modified_date` is `timestamptz`

Comment: `timestamptz` is a a pg column type, is this converted into `character` or `POSIXct` when it's an R data frame? knowing this would help what methods are being used when using `as.Date()`. using an invalid timezone as @r2evans pointed out is likely the underlying issue here

Comment: Oh, I understand @EJJ, the column type in R for last_modified_date is `POSIXct`

Comment: So what happens when you replace `tz="PET"` with `tz="America/Lima"`?

Comment: Hello @r2evans, it worked and converted to `2020-05-29`. This problem was quite strange, from R or SQL side. Thank you for the solution, I don't understand why R gave a different date but I guess the documentation will help

Comment: Trying to use a timezone that R does not recognize is assuredly going to cause unreliable/unacceptable results. In this case, it should be clear that `"PET"` is not recognized, so you need to learn how to find time zones that R *does* recognize, i.e., those found in `OlsonNames()` (it's a looooooong vector, recommend `head(OlsonNames())` for a quick glimpse). I didn't know ahead of time what zones were available, so I did `grep("Peru|Lima", OlsonNames(), value=TRUE)` to find something that looked credible.

Comment: In addition to only knowing specific timezones, one "quirk" of R is that while it *does not* recognize `tz="CST"`, the call `as.POSIXct("2020-01-01", tz="US/Central")` returns `"2020-01-01 CST"`, so one would *think* that R **does** in fact know what `CST` means. So yes, some things about R and timestamps and such are quirky, but once one realizes that not all human-intuitive timezone abbreviations are recognized by R, there are tools to find the correct name that R does recognize. In this case, perusing `OlsonNames()`. Glad it worked for you, good luck.

Comment: I appreciate very much your time and great explanation @r2evans, this problem has me awake since midnight and I didn't understand why in DBeaver I saw the right date, but in R I couldn't. Have a great weekend and again, thank you very much, gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was solved by adding the following code to the query:

```
--- Time zone is critical for this project
SET timezone = 'America/Lima';
SELECT loid_last, last_modified_date, 
date(last_modified_date) loid_creation_date 
FROM table 
WHERE loid_last = 'LIB3149';
```

After that, the retrieval was easily done with R and the dates are correct.